# Repos missing suddenly in azure container registry instance

Tags: azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

Repos missing suddenly in azure container registry instance.
There were lots of repos in ACR instance and now i am seeing its not available.
Can you help here.

It says "unable to send request to fetch repositories"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your repositories or tags not available in azure portal I would suggest you use the Firefox or Chrome to list all of your registry's repositories.

> To unable to send request to fetch repositories

***It's possible to fetch repositories but the browser may be unable to send the server's request to fetch repositories.***

- Make sure the registration portal you are using from a public network ***it's allows only private access.***
- To prevent these issues, Ensure your network connectivity is sufficient, DNS mistakes & Ads blockers.
- And check whether you have enabled ***firewall***.

Try to run this command `az acr check-health -n yourRegistry` using Azure CLI to determine whether your environment can connect to the Container Registry. To avoid any expired cookie, try to use incognito or private session in your browser.

**Reference:** [Azure Container Registry | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-faq)

Comment: Thanks it helped, I opened it InPrivate mode in microsoft edge and it worked